# Which the query datetime_add and datetime_sub more faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, datetime-format

I have an interview questions,
Which of the two SQL statements below would be faster? Assume that the table is indexed using the registration_timestamp column. Explain why.

Query 1

```
SELECT 
  name
FROM 
  user_table
WHERE 
  DATE(DATETIME_ADD(registration_timestamp, INTERVAL 7 HOUR))
         >= DATE(‘2018-01-01’)
  AND 
  DATE(DATETIME_ADD(registration_timestamp, INTERVAL 7 HOUR)) 
         < DATE(‘2019-01-01’)
```

Query 2

```
SELECT 
  name
FROM 
  user_table
WHERE 
  registration_timestamp
>= DATETIME_SUB(‘2018-01-01’, INTERVAL 7 HOUR)
  AND 
  registration_timestamp
< DATETIME_SUB(‘2019-01-01’, INTERVAL 7 HOUR)
```

i'm using sql and bigquery but syntax did not correct. Any idea ?

Comment: The syntax for the second version actually looks correct, other than that you are using curly quotes instead of double/single quotes.

Comment: Why the MySQL tag??

Answer (score 1):

The second one hands down.

The first one suffers from the "expression on the left hand operator" syndrome. An expression on the column defeats the use of the index.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the table has an index on `registration_timestamp`, then most likely that index could only be used in the second version, which is *sargable*.  The first version, which has `registration_timestamp` appearing inside a function call, would generally not be able to use the index.  So, you should generally stick with the second version.

Comment: Crap. Tim is here. That means it's time for me to go to sleep. +1

Comment: @TheImpaler I am in Singapore, I'm guessing you are somewhere in the US?  I feel the same way about Gordon Linoff, but luckily he and I are about 12 hours apart, so...

Answer (score 1):

Second Query would be faster than first one.

**Reason**: Indexing will not be used if you do casting or some manipulation on the indexed column causing your query to run as a simple query. But in second Query indexed are intact and manipulation are done on input only, which can directly use the range index in this case to perform search faster.

A good explanation you can found with example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable/799616#799616)